# Pro AngularJS Chp 07 Checkout Summary

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've been working my way through Pro AngularJS by Adam Freeman and am stumped as to why my cart summary is not matching his example. For some reason the ng-repeat that lists the items in the cart is not executing, even though the thead and tfoot that depend on the same collection are displaying correctly. I've gone back through the text and example code and the fact that a simple ng-repeat isn't working makes me think I've made the kind of mistake I'm just not going to be able to catch on my own.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**This is how the book says it should look like:**
[image]

**This is what mine looks like:** (yes, I know I'm missing the "Your Cart")
[image]

The HTML that is rendered looks like this:

```
<div ng-hide="cartData.length == 0" class="">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Price</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Subtotal</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!-- ngRepeat: item in cartData -->
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="text-right">Total:</td>
                    <td classs="text-right" class="ng-binding">$971.85</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>

        <div class="text-center">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#/products">Continue Shopping</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#/placeorder">Place order now</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my /components/cart/cart.js

```
angular.module("cart", [])
.factory("cart", function(){

    var cartData = [];

    return {

        addProduct: function (id, name, price) {
            var addedToExistingItem = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++){
                if (cartData[i].id == id) {
                    cartData[i].count++;
                    addedToExistingItem = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!addedToExistingItem) {
                cartData.push({
                    count: 1, id: id, price: price, name: name
                });
            }
        },

        removeProduct: function (id) {
            for (var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
                if (cartData[i].id == id){
                    cartData.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        },

        getProducts: function () {
            return cartData;
        }
    }
})
.directive("cartSummary", function (cart) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "components/cart/cartSummary.html",
        controller: function ($scope) {

            var cartData = cart.getProducts();

            $scope.total = function (){
                var total = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
                    total += (cartData[i].price * cartData[i].count);
                }
                return total;
            }

            $scope.itemCount = function () {
                var total = 0; 
                for (var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
                    total += cartData[i].count;
                }
                return total;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Here is my /controllers/checkoutControllers.js

```
angular.module("sportsStore")
.controller("cartSummaryController", function($scope, cart){

        $scope.cartData = cart.getProducts();

        $scope.total = function() {
            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.cartData.length; i++) {
                total += ($scope.cartData[i].price * $scope.cartData[i].count);
            }
            return total;
        }

        $scope.remove = function (id) {
            cart.removeProduct(id);
        }
    });
```

Finally, here is my /views/checkoutSummary.html

```
<div ng-cotroller="cartSummaryController">
    <div class="alert alert-warning" ng-show="cartData.length == 0">
        There are no products in your shopping cart.
        <a href="#/products" class="alert-link">Click here to return to the catalogue</a>
    </div>

    <div ng-hide="cartData.length == 0">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Price</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Subtotal</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in cartData">
                    <td class="text-center">{{item.count}}</td>
                    <td class="text-left">{{item.name}}</td>
                    <td class="text-right">{{item.price | currency}}</td>
                    <td class="text-right">{{ (item.price * item.count) | currency}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button ng-click="remove(item.id)" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Remove</button>
                    </td> 
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="text-right">Total:</td>
                    <td classs="text-right">{{total() | currency}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>

        <div class="text-center">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#/products">Continue Shopping</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#/placeorder">Place order now</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a typo here `<td classs="text-right">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your checkoutSummary.html, you have:

```
<div ng-cotroller="cartSummaryController">
```

Which should actually be:

```
<div ng-controller="cartSummaryController">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot trevor! I had a feeling it had to be some kind of typo but I never would have thought the controller was "missing" since the total was showing.